# Writing HTTP 401, 404, 500 responses to nginx error log instead of access log

Tags: nginx

I'm running the nginx 1.4.2 web server on a few of my servers and have noticed that all of the HTTP 401, 404 and 500 responses are being logged to the access log file instead of the error log file.

Is there some way to configure nginx to log HTTP 401, 404 and 500 responses to the error log instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont modify nginx source or develop 3rd nginx module, there is no way to do this.

You should know that `error_log` message is hard coded into nginx source or 3rd nginx module.
`error_log` is information which helps you know what nginx did.
An example in nginx source is as following:

```
ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_INFO, c->log, 0, "client sent too large request");
```

And `access_log` message is a record of one http request.
So it is best not to put `access_log` and `error_log` in the same file.

BTW, it is a good idea to develop a 3rd module which can log requests to different file according to response status.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed as much but was hoping I was wrong.